# XMLElement - Override Output format

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

what method would i need to override with a custom XmlElement to format the body in a certain order?

Currently, when the class is instantiated, i have it auto-fill the Default Value from the DefaultValueAttribute and create the initial child elements through the constructor.

What i want to do is make sure that the Elements child nodes are in a certain order.  This is not a webservices Xml Transformation but a simple file output for a User Interface.

I tried overriding InnerXml but that was a bust.  If i dont create the initial child elements from the constructor then they never show up.

## Updated

### Sample Dis-ordered output:

```
<ElementType name="RGB">
  <superType type="Class" />
  <element name="Alpha" type="int">
    <default>255</default>
  </element>
  <element name="R" type="int">
    <default>0</default>
  </element>
  <element name="G" type="int">
    <default>0</default>
  </element>
  <element name="B" type="int">
    <default>0</default>
  </element>
</ElementType>
```

### Sample Ordered output:

```
<ElementType name="RGB">
  <superType type="Class" />
  <element name="R" type="int">
      <default>0</default>
  </element>
  <element name="G" type="int">
      <default>0</default>
  </element>
  <element name="B" type="int">
      <default>0</default>
  </element>
  <element name="Alpha" type="int">
    <default>255</default>
  </element>
</ElementType>
```

Actual output would not be in a XSLT format but this should get the format i am looking for.  Currently, what ever is edited last is at the bottom, and i want to have the various object properties to be outputed in a certain order in the ChildNodes of the parent.  I want to have the iteration overload to a minimum.  I would rather handle the childnode creation be handled on the output of the class into XML format.

Comment: `in a certain order` which order? A sample input and output would make the life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after reviewing the errors of my coding, found that i was overriding the OuterXML property incorrectly.

Here was the resulting implementation of another class but is the same answer to my question.

```
public override string OuterXml {
  get {
    this.AppendChild( this.Location );
    this.AppendChild( this.Size );
    this.AppendChild( this.Hotspot );
    foreach( RGB shad in this.Shading ) {
      this.AppendChild( shad );
    }
    foreach( RGB spec in this.Specular ) {
      this.AppendChild( spec );
    }
    return base.OuterXml;
  }
```

## Updated:

Only Caveat to this solution is that 2nd level children elements do not get represented in OuterXml, even though i override the OuterXml in the 2nd level child elements.

### Question #2

What method(s) do i need to override so that OuterXml catches n-tier level of child element/objects?